# Not a supported ISO 4217 currency code: GBP

Tags: java, android

How to extract the currency symbol using currency which is like string "GBP" i am using

```
String s = obj.getCurrency().toString();
Currency currency=Currency.getInstance(s);
```

but it was throwing this exception :

```
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.primesoft.games.potshot/com.primesoft.games.potshot.PotshotActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a supported ISO 4217 currency code: GBP 
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-31 11:40:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(3929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
```

Comment: Check for whitespace in `s`?

Comment: Check code should be specific formatsee this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104084/convert-three-letter-currency-designation-to-symbol-designation-ex-usd-20-to-2