# Convert three-letter currency designation to symbol designation (ex USD 20 to $20) effeciently

Tags: java, currency

I have a formatted string which is equal to `USD 20`

I want to convert it into `$20`.

How can I do it efficient? Should I do it with regular expression but since with change in locale the country ISOCode will also change.

Comment: It is highly likely that efficiency is *irrelevant*.  What is more important is that the implementation is functionally correct, and that the functional requirements themselves are correct / meaningful.  So far the requirements are "a few fingers short of a handwave".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What You need is this

```
      import java.util.Currency; 
      import java.util.Locale;
```

.

```
      // create a currency for US locale
      Locale locale = Locale.US;
      Currency curr = Currency.getInstance(locale);

      // get and print the symbol of the currency
      StringBuilder symbol =  new StringBuilder(curr.getSymbol(locale));
      System.out.println("Currency symbol is = " + symbol);
```

and then just concatenate the Amount to the symbol.

> In this case, if the Locale changes, you will need to change it **only
>   in locale object.** The rest of the logic will be the same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should work for you (this assumes that some `String s` has been declared and initialized):

```
Currency localCurrForJVM = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
String localCurrencySymbol = localCurrForJVM.getSymbol();

s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""); 
//using regex to replace all non-numeric, non-decimal characters with ""

s = new StringBuilder(s).insert(0, localCurrencySymbol).toString(); 
//prepends the symbol to the StringBuilder, which replaces s
```

Some references:

```
public static Locale getDefault()
```

> Gets the current value of the default locale for this instance of the
>   Java Virtual Machine.
>
> The Java Virtual Machine sets the default locale during startup based
>   on the host environment. It is used by many locale-sensitive methods
>   if no locale is explicitly specified. It can be changed using the
>   setDefault method.

and:

```
public static Currency getInstance(Locale locale)
```

> Returns the Currency instance for the country of the given locale.
>   The language and variant components of the locale are ignored. The
>   result may vary over time, as countries change their currencies. For
>   example, for the original member countries of the European Monetary
>   Union, the method returns the old national currencies until December
>   31, 2001, and the Euro from January 1, 2002, local time of the
>   respective countries.
>
> Parameters:
>           locale - the locale for whose country a Currency instance is needed
>
> Returns:
>           the Currency instance for the country of the given locale, or null